# UseEffect - Use state to create an external Link

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I have a method `getUrl()` calling an API endpoint

```
  useEffect(() => {
    getUrl()
      .then(x => x.json())
      .then(x => {
        const { result } = x;
      });
  });
```

I can see in the Console the call in my page as you can see in the screenshot this is my data

```
{
   "result":"https://www.google.it",
   "error":null,
   "errorCode":null,
   "isSuccessful":true,
   "operationStatusCode":"OK"
}
```

How can I display the following `result` link example https://www.gooole.it in an external link in my view?

Do I have to use states?

I need an example of how to code to do this here

```
<a target="_blank" href={result}>Google Link</a>
```

[image]

Comment: Can you explain exactly what you want, I read over and over your question. but I don't understand exactly, do you need to call the `getUrl()` function after clicking the anchor?

Comment: I think you need to store result in state.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to use a state in your component :

```
const [url,setUrl] = useState('');
```

and render it :

```
<a target="_blank" href={url}>Google Link</a>
```

and in the use effect :

```
useEffect(() => {
   getUrl()
     .then(x => x.json())
     .then(x => {
        const { result } = x;
        // use set url hook 
        setUrl(result);
      });
  });
```

Comment: I would advise to mention to add an empty array `[]` inside the `effect` to avoid calling api on every render. maybe he missed that.

Answer (score 1):

> Do I have to use states?

Yes! you should use state object to maintain the fresh results as setState can be async and when you update the state a rerender takes place and UI gets updated. Check this:

Put this to initialize the state:

```
const [result, setResult] = useState({});
```

where `result` is a property and `setResult` will be the updater method.

Now you have to use it in the component's template such as :

```
{ result && <a target="_blank" href={result}>Google Link</a> }
{/* if result (its a promise) is not available when render happens then it might err. */}
```

Now in your `useEffect`:

```
useEffect(() => {
    getUrl()
      .then(x => x.json())
      .then(x => {
        const { result } = x;
        setResult(result); // <-----------set it here
      });
  },[result]); //<---pass it here it rerenders when state.result changes after first render.
```

Answer (score 1):

One thing more I would like to suggest that making API calls in useEffect is not a good practice. React documentation also says to avoid the API calls in useEffect. Instead, create a function that will make the required API call and call that function in the useEffect.

```
const getUrl = () =>{
    /*make your API call here*/
}

useEffect(()=>{
    getUrl()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to do that

> First Usecase - will use useState

```
const [url,setUrl] = useState(''); //set useState

useEffect(() => {  //useEffect to get data on componentDidMount ans assign it to url
   getUrl()
     .then(x => x.json())
     .then(x => {
        const { result } = x;           
        setUrl(result); // placing data in useState
      });
  },[])

<a target="_blank" href={url}>Google Link</a>
```

> Second Usecase - Declare one variable in your component and assign the response from api call to variable and used that

```
let url = ''
useEffect(() => {  //useEffect to get data on componentDidMount ans assign it to url
   getUrl()
     .then(x => x.json())
     .then(x => {
        url = x.result; //Assigning the result to url
      });
  },[])

<a target="_blank" href={url}>Google Link</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should have separated file that contains all API calls:

```
// apiList.js

export const getUrl = (url, params) => axios.get(url, params).then(res => res.data);

etc
```

Then on your function component:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { getUrl } from '[pathTo]/apiList';

const YourComponent = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useState({});
  useEffect(async () => {
    const result = await getUrl() || {};
    setState(result);
  }, []);


  return (
    <a target="_blank" href={state.result}>Google Link</a>
  );
};
```

On `useEffect` the call happens and the `setState` function changes the state of the component and the re-render will happen. then you see your `a` tag has a new value for its `href` attribute.